# Upgrade MongoDB from 2.6 to 4.2.6

Tags: mongodb, nosql, version, upgrade

I need to update MongoDB from version `2.6` to `4.2.6`.

Could you please suggest effective way to upgrade the version without losing data or any kind of trouble.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is some general information: [Upgrade a standalone to 4,2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-standalone/). Specifics about upgrading from`2.6` to `4.2` may vary. Note that there is no version `4.6` yet (I think you mean `4.2.6`, and I edit your post to correct it).

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was my mistake. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Each version has its associated [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2/).

Upgrades must be done one version at a time (2.6 -> 3.0 -> 3.2 etc.).

Read the 3.0 release notes, identify which of them apply to your application, follow them, install 3.0 binaries, test your application, bump FCV if applicable (does not apply to 3.0 but will apply to later versions), test your application again, repeat the process for 3.2, etc.